# mixins Django how to enable staff-user post, edit, delete permission in html template

Tags: python, django

I am using **mixins** in my views for restrict unauthenticated user to access my blog-post page, edit-page and delete-page. Right now only admin user can access those page but I also give permission to staff user for access those page. see the picture:
[image]

still now my staff user get 404 error when trying to access those page. here is my code:

**#views.py**

```
class blog_publish_view(PermissionRequiredMixin,CreateView):
      raise_exception = True
      permission_required = "blog_add_blog"
      model = Post
      form_class = BlogPost
      template_name = "blog_post.html"
      #fields = ['title','author','body']
      
      
                   
class blog_update_view(PermissionRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
      raise_exception = True
      permission_required = "blog_change_blog"
      model = Post
      template_name = "blog_update_post.html"
      form_class = BlogPost
     
     
     


class blog_delete_view(PermissionRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
      raise_exception = True
      permission_required = "blog_delete_blog"
      model = Post
      template_name = "delete_blog_post.html"
      success_url = reverse_lazy('blog')
```

**#my html page for post blog:**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Publish Blog</h1>  
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
           
            {{form.media}}
           
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button class="btn btn-info">Publish</button>
        </form>
        </div>
{% endif %}
```

my staff user can post,edit,publish blog from django admin panel but how to enable those permission in html template.

Comment: Isn't it permission_required = "blog_change_post" ? Or something including post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the `permission_required` attribute incorrectly. The permission names are the form of `<app label>.<permission codename>`, where the default permission code names are in the form of `<action>_<model_name>`. So your views would be like:

```
class blog_publish_view(PermissionRequiredMixin,CreateView):
      ...
      permission_required = "blog.add_post"
      ...


class blog_update_view(PermissionRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
      ...
      permission_required = "blog.change_post"
      ...


class blog_delete_view(PermissionRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
      ...
      permission_required = "blog.delete_post"
      ...
```

**Edit**: The default permissions are as follows:

1. Add permission: `<app label>.add_<lowercase_model_name>`
2. Change permission: `<app label>.change_<lowercase_model_name>`
3. Delete permission: `<app label>.delete_<lowercase_model_name>`
4. View permission: `<app label>.view_<lowercase_model_name>`

> **Note**: Class names should be in `PascalCase` not <s>`snake_case`</s> so it should be `BlogPublishView` instead of
> <s>`blog_publish_view`</s>, etc. Have a look at [PEP 8 -- Style Guide
> for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: can you please describe little bit more.  it will be better if you can show me an example by writing one or two line code.

Comment: @boyenec what do you mean describe more? I already show you that you need to change the values you set for `permission_required` and also show the values you need to set it to in the code...

Comment: @boyenec you had specified the attribute as `blog_add_blog` while it should infact be `blog.add_post` as I show.

Comment: Thanks it worked.  "_post" is it default django attribute?? is there any attribute like  "blog.view_post?? for showing specific page to specific group of users?

Comment: `post` is your model name in lowercase. Yes there would be a `blog.view_post` permission, check my edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232292/discussion-between-boyenec-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).